# How can i call lua function that takes self as a parameter from C?

Tags: c, function, lua

For example, If I have function like

```
foo = function(self) print ("Foo") end
```

to call this function, I would say, `foo:()`

How do I call this kind of function from C?

Answer (score 4):

`foo:()` is not legal.

That function would need to be in a table for the `:` call syntax to work.

```
tab = {
    foo = function(self)
        print "Foo"
    end
}
tab:foo()
```

The important thing to know is that `tab:foo()` is just syntactic sugar for `tab.foo(tab)` (only `tab` is only evaluated once).

So to call that manually you just need to pass the object as the first argument yourself.